# Tkinter: In a custom widget, how do I set the value of a custom variable through .configure?

Tags: class, tkinter, widget

I would like to use this command to set my custom variable, how to do this:

```
self.ent1.configure(my_custom_var='teste')
```

I want my custom variable to be part of the .configure dictionary

sample code:

```
from tkinter import *

class My_Entry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent, my_custom_var='', *args, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)


        #print('my_custom value: ', my_custom_var)
        print(self['my_custom_var'])

        return


    def configure(self, **kwargs):
        super().configure(**kwargs)
        print(kwargs) #<--- my custom var here in kwargs

#--------------


class Mainframe(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        #self.ent1 = My_Entry(self, my_custom_var='teste')
        self.ent1 = My_Entry(self)
        self.ent1.configure(show='*')
        #self.ent1.configure(show='*', my_custom_var='teste')
        self.ent1.pack()
        return


if __name__== '__main__':
    app = Mainframe()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: do you want to change an instance attribute like this? (just incorporating it in the `configure` method)

Comment: You should pass it as in your commented out line, then pop it into another variable, before `super().__init__()` in your `My_Entry` class.

Comment: I want my custom variable to be part of the .configure dictionary. Could you show an example? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tkinter doesn't have a way to add an option that works exactly like the built-in options. However, you can override `configure` and `cget` to handle both your custom options and the default options.

Here's an example of one way to do it, though it's not the only way.

```
class My_Entry(tk.Entry):
    # tuple of supported custom option names
    custom_options = ("my_custom_var",)

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, my_custom_var='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.configure(my_custom_var=my_custom_var, **kwargs)

    def configure(self, **kwargs):
        for key in self.custom_options:
            if key in kwargs:
                setattr(self, key, kwargs.pop(key))
        if kwargs:
            super().configure(**kwargs)

    def cget(self, key):
        if key in self.custom_options:
            return getattr(self, key)
        else:
            return super().cget(key)
```

This lets you use either `cget` or directly access the class attribute:

```
entry = My_Entry(root, width=40, my_custom_var="Hello, world")
print(f"custom var via cget: {entry.cget('my_custom_var')}")
print(f"custom var via attribute: {entry.my_custom_var}")
```

And within the class, you can do likewise:

```
print(f"custom var via cget: {self.cget('my_custom_var')}")
print(f"custom var via attribute: {self.my_custom_var}")
```